# How to create a jquery slider with next and previous button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

How to create a jquery slider with next and previous button
slider contain the drag drop element?

Comment: Here you can post a question about problems on your code where people can try to answer and solve the issue... we can not do all the work for you.

Comment: This is like asking "How do I build a house?"

Answer (score 0):

I really like JQuery flexslider for this. Maybe you can take a look at that plugin: 
http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/

Answer (score 0):

Just use some JQuery plugin, i prefer [Jquery Cycle Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) (it is realy great and easy tool). You can also read some random tutorials and create it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Flow Slider is your best choice. It can slide on events such as back and forward button click. You can also start the "Drag" controller so it works on dragging. [Flow Slider nowadays is my favorite choice for jQuery slider](http://www.flowslider.com).